# Create a JIRA ticket via service desk api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a ticket in JIRA by following https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/3.6.2/#servicedeskapi/request-createCustomerRequest

I send a post request to  ***https:/x.atlassian.net//rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/request***

With following json param

```
    {
     "serviceDeskId": “1”,
     "requestTypeId": “1”,
     "requestFieldValues": {
     "summary": "Request raised via service REST API",
     "description": "test."
     }

}
```

But it replied with  **404 error**

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Invalid project key 'request'",
    "i18nErrorMessage": {
        "i18nKey": "sd.error.project.by.key.not.found",
        "parameters": [
            "request"
        ]
    }
}
```

*Update - the service desk id and request type id  got from a response of rest/servicedeskapi/request/{issueid}. Therefore values used for service desk id request type id can not be wrong*

I tried ***servicedesk/1/requesttype/1/field*** and I received

```
{
    "requestTypeFields": [
        {
            "fieldId": "summary",
            "name": "Subject",
            "description": "",
            "required": true,
            "defaultValues": [],
            "validValues": [],
            "jiraSchema": {
                "type": "string",
                "system": "summary"
            }
        },
        {
            "fieldId": "description",
            "name": "Body",
            "description": "",
            "required": false,
            "defaultValues": [],
            "validValues": [],
            "jiraSchema": {
                "type": "string",
                "system": "description"
            }
        }
    ],
    "canRaiseOnBehalfOf": true,
    "canAddRequestParticipants": true
}
```

I am not able to understand what am I missing. Can someone please advice

Answer (score 2):

Issue was with the url. There is an unnecessary 'servicedesk' in the url.
After removing that it worked.

```
https:/x.atlassian.net//rest/servicedeskapi/request
```